# Drupal db_insert('node') promote to front page equel to 1 not working

Tags: mysql, drupal, publish

I'm using the following code for promoting to front page but it's not working. It is inserting entry in node table only. I need to insert entry into another table to promote it.

Node table showing `promote=1` value in the table but the issue is while checking it through drupal admin and editing article, it's not showing checked check box or not displaying to front page.

```
$insert = db_insert('node')
    ->fields(array(
    'title' => $rtitle,
    //'vid' => '',
    'type' => 'article',
    'language' => 'und',    
    'uid' => '1',
    'created' => $pubdate,
    //'comment' => '',
    'promote' => '1',
    //'sticky' => '',
    //'tnid' => '',
    'status' => '1',
))
->execute();
```

So the promote=1 is not display to front page. also all the variables are working fine and query is also working correctly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwQhH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the native Drupal method for creating a node in code?

```
  global $user;

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->title = "My Cool Article";
  $node->type = "article";
  node_object_prepare($node);
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->uid = $user->uid; 
  $node->status = 1; 
  $node->promote = 1; 
  $node->comment = 0;

  node_save($node);
```

Comment: Its not working as well. Is their any reference need to insert into another table ? Or Another table records needs to insert ?

Comment: I insert record into node_revision table promote=1 and it's solved.